# Can't import db in Windows Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am getting the following failure from the below code. I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10:

```
from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

I've installed Flask and SQLAlchemy

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

def __repr__(self):
return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you edit your code for it to be legible? You can read more on how to format code blocks [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python:Select Interpreter`

[image]

Choose the **correct** interpreter (*Installed the Flask and SQLAlchemy package*).

You can  also use the following code to verify the current interpreter path. Then install the required packages for the current interpreter.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```